# Get max col value and make it a new variable

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df = data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                score=c(11,NA,7,NA,NA,4,6,9,15),
                MAKE=c(11,11,11,4,4,4,15,15,15))
```

Say you have data as above with `group` and `score` and the objective is to make new variable `MAKE` which is just the maximum value of `score` for each `group` repeated.

And this is my attempt yet it does not work.

```
df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(Value = max(is.na(score)))
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up `is.na` and `na.omit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(MAKE = max(score, na.rm = TRUE)) 
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group score  MAKE
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    11    11
# 2     1    NA    11
# 3     1     7    11
# 4     2    NA     4
# 5     2    NA     4
# 6     2     4     4
# 7     3     6    15
# 8     3     9    15
# 9     3    15    15
```

The issue with `max(is.na(score))` is that `is.na(score)` is a logical vector and when `max` is applied, it gets coerced to a binary vector with 1 for `TRUE` and 0 for `FALSE`. A somewhat less natural solution but closer to what you tried then would be

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(MAKE = max(score[!is.na(score)]))
```

which finds the maximal value among all those values of `score` that are not NA.